# using mongdb in docker with Go

Tags: mongodb, docker, go, docker-compose, protocol-buffers

i tried to run MongoDB in docker-compose and connect my Go server with MongoDB in docker seem not to work for me, thought i already use `mongodb:MyContanerName:27017`

when i run my go server and then i tired to request on my client, the error something like this

```
2019/09/08 14:10:37 Unexpected error: rpc error: code = Internal desc = internal error: server selection error: server selection timeout
current topology: Type: Unknown
Servers:
Addr: mongo:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection(mongo:27017[-125]) connection is closed
```

i already did docker-compose up -d for my docker, and it was running on my docker ,

the full code is trigger here [golang and mongodb](https://slexy.org/view/s206Zrx5GN)

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to [the question itself by editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57840017/edit) . Should the link become invalid, the question as well as the answers might not make any sense.

Comment: Adding excerpts of your mongod.conf would not harm either, specifically the `replication` and `net` sections.